# greenDAO - Date type, returning 1/jan/1970

Tags: android, sqlite, greendao

Using the greenDAO generator i use:

```
entity.addDateProperty("date").notNull();
```

I insert the value: **'2013-10-30'**, and when i check on my database i have the value there.
I checked this value with this query:

```
select datetime(date) from myTable;
```

and it returns:
**2013-10-10 00:00:00**

now in android, when i try to retrieve this value i do (for each row):

```
myTable.getDate();
```

which always returns **01/01/1970**.

What i found (but might not be the cause for this problem):

1. I did some debug in my code, and i found out that the class myTableDao.java, generated by greenDAO, on method **public void readEntity(Cursor cursor, History_Job entity, int offset)** is returning the value "2013" from the cursor:

   entity.setDate(new java.util.Date(cursor.getLong(offset + 1)));
2. Still inside myTableDao.java, method **createTable()** i have this field declared as Integer.

   ...
   "'DATE' INTEGER NOT NULL ," + // 1: date
   ...

Am i doing something wrong with the property DATE, or is it a bug on greenDAO when trying to use this type of field?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, Have you found any solution yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GreenDao always returns Date in that particular format. You can call it a bug.

You can see the code here

**[https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO](https://github.com/jatinmalwal/greenDAO)**

What you can do is

- fork GreenDao from [here](https://github.com/jatinmalwal/greenDAO)
- Add a method setDateFormat(String format) and also contributes to others.

See doc of **S[QLite Date Datatypes here.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_data_types.htm)**

SQLite stores date in three formats **TEXT,REAL and INTEGER** so its all about the GreenDao method which is returning date to you. You can make it modify.

Answer (score 2):

GreenDao uses Java Date objects in the Entities and stores their Date.getTime() (time-in-millis-since-epoch) value as a SQLite INTEGER. This works just fine both ways if you use it properly. I'm not sure why you're manually inserting dates - that defeats the purpose of using an ORM library.

Comment: im inserting this value using an external .sql file. If my app is installed from the scratch i want some values already on my DB, for this i have an external sql file that populates my DB.

Comment: Anyone know why does GreenDAO convert date to integer, while SQLite supports DateTime type?